# Closed subgroups of algebraic group have DCC?

Tags: group-theory, connectedness, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

Are there any infinite descending chains of closed subgroups of the general linear group over a field? More specifically, is my argument ok? Can you fill in some of the details?

**Prop:** No.

*Proof:* If we define $|H| = ( \dim(H), [ H:H_0 ] )$ where $H_0$ is the connected component of the identity and if we order these “cardinalities” lexicographically, then I claim that in any chain $H < K$ that $|H| < |K|$. Since the ordered pairs of non-negative integers has no infinite descending chains, the same is then true for the closed subgroups. Proof of the claim: Consider $H_0, K_0$. I claim $H_0 \leq K_0$ [ but I'm not sure why ]. Since these are both connected, either $H_0 = K_0$ or $\dim(H) =\dim(H_0) <  \dim(K_0) = \dim(K)$. In the former case we clearly have $[H:H_0] < [K:H_0] = [K:K_0]$. Hence in both cases we have $|H| < |K|$. $\square$

So other than “are there any mistakes I don't know about?” I'm asking “if $H$ is a closed subgroup of the algebraic group $K$, is it always the case that $H_0 \leq K_0$?”

---

*Background*: My setup for algebraic groups is groups whose underlying set is a subset of the set of invertible matrices over an algebraically closed field that is the zero set of a set of polynomials in its entries and determinant, such that multiplication and inversion are similarly given by polynomials in the entries and determinant. I think that's a standard definition, so feel free to fix it if I stated something incorrectly.

If you are flexible on references, I prefer the textbook by Malle–Testerman (2011).

*Motivation:* I want to show that unipotent groups have a useful normalizer condition, so I want to say they have ACC on closed subgroups. However, I noticed that $K^\times$ lacks ACC on closed subgroups, and by extension every torus, and by extension every Borel subgroup. However, I couldn't think of any violations of DCC, and I read about this "dimension" idea, and it seemed plausible that I could give this analogue of order. My hope is that ACC for closed unipotent subgroups will hold for similar dimension reasons, but first thing is first.

Comment: Wouldn't an infinite descending chain of closed sets in $GL_n$ correspond to an infinite ascending chain of ideals in the Noetherian ring $k[GL_n]$?

Comment: Sounds good. Can you translate that into the connected component thing too? I'm sure it is something simple about prime ideals.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want connected components to be involved.  The DCC doesn't hold inside them or modulo them because both of those things are again algebraic groups.

Comment: "Does hold"?  DCC by itself is not enough for me. This is part of a larger goal described in the question. I need a variety of proof techniques, and I seriously doubt the coordinate ring is going to be artinian in any of my examples.

Comment: Yea, "does hold" :)

Comment: I don't think ACC holds in general for unipotent groups.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but $(K, +)$ is a unipotent group (it's strictly upper triangular $2 \times 2$ matrices) and when $K = \overline{\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z}$ the finite fields give an infinite ascending chain of closed subgroups.

Comment: Yuck, I was thinking they weren't closed, but they are zeros of x^q-x. I don't think this is a problem for the overall goal, but it is a problem for this line of argument. Back to the drawing board. Thanks!

Comment: BTW I still want to know about $H\leq K \implies H_0 \leq K_0$. I think my core argument is still only going to work for connected groups, but will need to handle not connected groups too, so I'll need to have some control.